# Python Azure ARM Template Deployment failed

Tags: python, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy a keyvault using ARM Templates. The template I am using as base is located at [azuredeploy.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/modules/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/1.0), If I do not provide parameters, the deployment succeed, however as soon as I add a parameters file, like the following one.
**Parameters file:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters":
  {
    "vaultName":
    {
      "value": <key vault name>
    }
  }
}
```

> **(InvalidTemplate)** Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters '$schema, contentVersion, parameters' in the
> parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original
> template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The
> only supported parameters for this template are 'vaultName, location,
> enabledForDeployment, enabledForDiskEncryption,
> enabledForTemplateDeployment, enablePurgeProtection,
> enableRbacAuthorization, enableSoftDelete, softDeleteRetentionInDays,
> tenantId, networkRuleBypassOptions, NetworkRuleAction, ipRules,
> accessPolicies, virtualNetworkRules, skuName, tags'. Please see
> https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for usage details.'.
> **#Code:** InvalidTemplate
> **#Message:** Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters '$schema, contentVersion, parameters' in the parameters
> file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and
> can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The only supported
> parameters for this template are 'vaultName, location,
> enabledForDeployment, enabledForDiskEncryption,
> enabledForTemplateDeployment, enablePurgeProtection,
> enableRbacAuthorization, enableSoftDelete, softDeleteRetentionInDays,
> tenantId, networkRuleBypassOptions, NetworkRuleAction, ipRules,
> accessPolicies, virtualNetworkRules, skuName, tags'. Please see
> https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for usage details.'.
> **Additional Information:Type:** TemplateViolation
> **Info:** {
> "lineNumber": 0,
> "linePosition": 0,
> "path": ""
> }

Based on the error message, the issue is at the parameters file, but I am not able to identify what is wrong. Do you have any clue where the error can be?

**Python Code:

```
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models import DeploymentMode
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models import Deployment
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models import DeploymentProperties
from miscellaneous.logger import Logger
from msrestazure.azure_cloud import get_cloud_from_metadata_endpoint
from uuid6 import uuid7
class AzureConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, subscriptionId, resourceGroup):
        self.logger = Logger("Azure Connection")
        self.logger.info("Retrieving the list of available endpoint")
        endpoints = get_cloud_from_metadata_endpoint(os.environ.get("ARM_ENDPOINT"))
        self.subscriptionId = subscriptionId
        self.resourceGroup = resourceGroup
        self.credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
        self.logger.info("Creating a client for deploying resources on subscription {}".format(self.subscriptionId))
        self.client = ResourceManagementClient(self.credentials, self.subscriptionId,
            base_url=endpoints.endpoints.resource_manager)
        self.logger.success("Client was successfully created")
    def deploy(self, template):
        resources = ""
        for resource in template.get("resources"):
            resources += "\n\t {}".format(resource.get("type"))
        self.logger.info("The following resources: {}\nwill be deployed".format(resources))
        deploymentProperties = DeploymentProperties(
            mode=DeploymentMode.incremental,
            template=template
        )
        self.logger.info("Attempting deploy operation")
        try:
            deployment_async_operation = self.client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(
                self.resourceGroup,
                uuid7(),
                Deployment(properties=deploymentProperties)
            )
        except:
            self.logger.error("The resources could not be deployed");
        self.logger.success("Resources were successfully deployed")
    def deployWithParameters(self, template, parameters):
        resources = ""
        for resource in template.get("resources"):
            resources += "\n\t {}".format(resource.get("type"))
        self.logger.info("The following resources: {}\nwill be deployed".format(resources))
        parameters = {k: {"value": v} for k, v in parameters.items()}
        deploymentProperties = DeploymentProperties(
            mode=DeploymentMode.incremental,
            template=template,
            parameters=parameters
        )
        self.logger.info("Attempting deploy operation")
        deployment_async_operation = self.client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(
            self.resourceGroup,
            uuid7(),
            Deployment(properties=deploymentProperties)
        )

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
azureConnection = AzureConnection(os.environ.get("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"), os.environ.get("AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP"))
with open((os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates", <fileName>), "r") as file:
  template = json.load(file)
with open((os.path.dirname(__file__), "parameters", <fileName>), "r") as file:
  json = json.load(file)
deployment = azureConnection.deployWithParameters(template, parameter)
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing a lot with the code, I came with a solution out of the box. It looks like that a parameters template is not required

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters":
  {
    "vaultName":
    {
      "value": <key vault name>
    }
  }
}
```

I just need to send the parameters without further structure Ex:

```
{
  "vaultName":
  {
    "value": <key vault name>
  },
  "location":
  {
    "value": <location value>
  },
  ...
}
```